# How do I connect mysql to python in pycharm. I currently use Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Can someone please help me connecting python to mysql. **I am new to *Ubuntu OS*** and don't know much about it. **I use PyCharm IDE**.
I installed mysql on my system and also installed the mysql.connector module correctly( **pip3 isntall mysql-connector-python** )
But it fails t connect and gives the error as follows:
**mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported**
When I run the same code in ***VS code*** I get an error which reads:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/velocity-linux/Desktop/Main Folder/Project.py", line 1, in 
import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector**
Please tell what can I do
The code which I use for connection is:

````
mydb1 = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root",
                                passwd="home@253144", database="school")``` 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGXKQ.png
````

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're getting the error in Visual Studio Code because you're using a [virtual environment](https://stackabuse.com/python-virtual-environments-explained/) in PyCharm.

The PyCharm error is the error you should be focusing on.

What imports are you using for this project? The error seems to be caused by an unsupported library, I am unsure if this is from your script or a script from the mysql-connector library.

Have you tried reinstalling mysql-connector with both `python -m pip uninstall mysql-connector` and `python -m pip install mysql-connector`?